# Using primary keys as index for active record reads, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

When I use users=User.where(...)
I can use users.find(id) to find by it's id

I want to use a hash such so that I can use users[id] as a means of searching, where the id becomes the index of the hash.

How do I do this?

I have tried:

```
users.to_a.map(&:serializable_hash)
users.map(&:attributes)
users.map { |r| r.attributes.symbolize_keys }
```

None of these worked in turning the primary key into the index

Comment: Some code that you would tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert any `Enumerable` into a Hash, you can use [`index_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by) from `ActiveSupport (activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb)`

```
users = User.where(...)
users.index_by(&:id)
# => { 1 => <User ...>, 2 => <User ...>, ...}

# note the difference between 'index_by' and 'group_by' where the latter will return an array of a single User for each id
users.group_by(&:id)
# => { 1 => [<User ...>], 2 => [<User ...>], ...}
```

As `ActiveRecord::Relation` includes the `Enumerable` module in its ancestors chain (you can check by `ActiveRecord::Relation.ancestors.include? Enumerable`), you can use any `Enumerable` instance methods on any `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Comment: That worked, but I had to do: users=users.index_by(&:id), thanks!

Comment: great to know! I intentionally left that for your modification, anyway :)

Comment: Nice.. didn't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

For the solution to your specific need

```
indexed_users = [] # holds users on index as id

users.each {|u| indexed_users[u.id] = u.attributes }
```

Also converting id as index is not a good idea as the array size may go out of control if id become bigger like thousands or so and ids are not sequential. like
`users = [<id: 1>, <id:200>]` will result in array with size of 201.

Updated  to get hash is as key

```
users.map(&:attributes).group_by { |attr| attr[:id] }
```

Comment: well, I don't want an array, I want a hash where user id is the index value, therefore I wouldn't have a massive array

Comment: Then simply use users.group_by &:id